# Problem setting up Blackberry development environment on Elcipse

Tags: blackberry

I am following the [Slashdev Blackberry development tutorial](http://www.slashdev.ca/2007/05/30/blackberry-development-with-ant-eclipse/) to setup BB development environment.

I am done with the first part of the tutorial, when i follow the [second part](http://www.slashdev.ca/2007/05/30/blackberry-development-with-ant-eclipse/2/).

then I get the following error on building the HelloWorldApp via Ant:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\acernet135\workspace\HelloWorld\res\build.xml:16: jde home must be a directory    
Total time: 172 milliseconds
```

Any help? How to sort this out? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Those instructions are pretty old. You should look at the [latest JDE Plug-in instructions](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Java+Plug-in+for+Eclipse+%28Win%29) and also look at my [Windows 7 notes](http://www.blackberryprogramming.com/tips/windows-7-jde-eclipse/) about this process.

Comment: The latest JDE plugin for eclipse i tried to download from the Blackberry's site is damaged. Wonder if you can provide me that file by uploading it to one of the file uploading sites like http://www.yousendit.com/. Can you?

Comment: @Maxood, try again, if it does not work, contact Blackberry support. That should really work.